# Aggregating a dataframe: weighted averages for numerical columns and concatenating as string for other types

Tags: python, pandas

I got a dataframe which looks like this:

```py
np.random.seed(11)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'item_id': np.random.randint(1, 4, 10),
    'item_type': [chr(x) for x in np.random.randint(65, 80, 10)],
    'value1': np.round(np.random.rand(10)*30, 1),
    'value2': np.round(np.random.randn(10)*30, 1),
    'n': np.random.randint(100, size=10)
})

   item_id item_type  value1  value2   n
0        2         A    26.8   -39.2  59
1        1         N    25.7   -33.6   1
2        2         A     5.0    22.1   3
3        2         N    19.0    47.2   8
4        1         M     0.6    -0.9  87
5        2         N     3.5   -20.5  81
6        3         E     9.5    32.9  68
7        1         C     4.7    -9.3  72
8        2         M    22.8    21.8  32
9        1         B    24.5    46.5  78
```

I would like to transform this dataframe to have a single row for each `item_id`.
The columns should be aggregated by finding the weighted average of `value1` and `value2` (weighted by `n`), and combining categorical variable `item_type` if it is not unique. The end result looks like this:

```
        item_type     value1     value2
item_id                                
1         B/C/M/N   9.778571  11.955882
2           A/M/N  15.089071 -15.474317
3               E   9.500000  32.900000
```

**What I have tried**

This can be done with a custom function and using `apply`, like this one:

```
def func(x):  
    record = ['/'.join(sorted(x.item_type.unique()))]
    total_rows = x.n.sum()
    for c in ['value1', 'value2']:
        record.append((x[c] * x.n / total_rows).sum())
    return pd.Series(record, index=['item_type', 'value1', 'value2'])
```

```
%%timeit
df.groupby('item_id').apply(func)

6.95 ms ± 30.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

This is for 10 records. I have a dataframe above 40 million records. I am searching for the most efficient way to do this, before I start thinking of going parallel. All other operations I've done on this dataframe take less than a minute, but this one is sloow.

any ideas appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure but may be worth a try. We can do a similar operation on a window using `transform` then group the results , string operations are quite slow in general:

```
(df.groupby("item_id")['item_type'].agg(lambda x: '/'.join(sorted(x.unique())))
 .to_frame()
 .join(
  df[['value1','value2']].mul(df['n'],0).div(
     df.groupby("item_id")['n'].transform('sum'),0)
 .groupby(df['item_id']).sum()))
```

Or :

```
cols = ['value1','value2']
(df.groupby("item_id")['item_type'].agg(lambda x: '/'.join(sorted(x.unique())))
 .to_frame().join
(pd.DataFrame(((df[cols].to_numpy() *   df['n'].to_numpy()[:,None])/
df.groupby("item_id")['n'].transform('sum').to_numpy()[:,None]),
 index=df.index,columns=cols)
.groupby(df['item_id']).sum()))
```

---

```
        item_type     value1     value2
item_id                                
1         B/C/M/N   9.778571  11.955882
2           A/M/N  15.089071 -15.474317
3               E   9.500000  32.900000
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using NumPy functions only:

```
def numpy_func(group):
    n = group['n'].values
    item_type = np.str.join('/', np.unique(group["item_type"].values))  

    value1 = np.average(group["value1"].values, weights = n)
    value2 = np.average(group["value2"].values, weights = n)

    return pd.Series([item_type, value1, value2], index=['item_type', 'value1', 'value2'])

df.groupby("item_id").apply(numpy_func)
```

---

**Execution time comparison**

I compared your function with mine:

```
from datetime import datetime

before = datetime.now()
for i in range(1000):
    df.groupby("item_id").apply(numpy_func)
after = datetime.now()
print(after - before)
#0:00:03.954935

before = datetime.now()
for i in range(1000):
    df.groupby("item_id").apply(func)
after = datetime.now()
print(after - before)
#0:00:06.307923
```

It was like 1/3 faster.

Comment: Thanks! tried variations of this, but not giving much gains, I think it has to do which the fact that each groups usually has only about 2 rows in my actual data.